# Django Overwrite existing instance in table

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a form in one page, then in another page I'm trying to pull out the form (populated with the data saved in it already) and would like to make changes to it so that when I save it it overwrites the instance instead of creating another one.

```
def edit(request):

   a = request.session.get('a',  None)

   if a is None:
       raise Http404('a was not found')

   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Name_Form(request.POST, instance=a)
       if form.is_valid():
           j = form.save( commit=False )
           j.save()
   else:
       form = Name_Form( instance = a )
```

This is the code I have for the "editting form" view.. When I open this page the form is successfully prepopulated with all the data. However, when I make changes and save, it does not overwrite the existing instance, instead it creates a new one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert
I think this may help you.

Update:
What about trying a more "explicit" way.
Assume, id_of_Name stores only the id or pk of your model which you want to edit (I assume the model is called "Name"). Then just retrieve the id/pk from session to query your db for the model instance. Also try to directly call the save method on the form.

```
def edit(request):

   id_of_Name = request.session.get('a',  None)

   if id_of_Name is None:
       raise Http404('id_of_Name was not found')
   instance = Name.objects.get(pk=id_of_Name)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Name_Form(request.POST, instance=instance)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
   else:
       form = Name_Form( instance = instance )
```

Comment: hmm, then it seems like the pk gets lost in the process. Doesnt save(force_update=True) work?

Comment: re: edit
i get a type error doing that... int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Name'

i'm honestly very confused.. what is really driving me crazy is that my original code seemed to be working at one point! and the logic seems sound! i dont get why it won't OVERWRITE the instance... grrr

Comment: Don't put the whole object instance into a, just the id/pk. Then there should be no type error.

Comment: That gets rid of the error fine! But we're back to our initial problem, it attempts to create a new instance, and when an instance already exists it throws back an error saying so. So still doesn't overwrite :S

Comment: The error message is one i customized. It's the one thrown back because of the non_field_error in the template. (I've got the fields defined as unique_together)